# Create relation between nodes with same property in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a new relation between two actors that have been born in the same year.

I'm running this query, but it seems not working:

```
MATCH (a:Person)
with a AS personA
MATCH (b:Person)
with b AS personB
WHERE personA.born = personB.born AND personA <> personB
CREATE UNIQUE (personA)-[:HAS_SAME_AGE {sameAge: "Has same age"}]-(personB)
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Relationships have distinct directions. Use (a)-[]->(b) and (a)<-[]-(b) instead.

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your query, the second `WITH` clause did not include `personA`, so that variable was dropped.
2. But both `WITH` clauses are not even needed in your query, and therefore should be omitted (for clarity, if nothing else).
3. Your query could also very easily just have a single `MATCH` clause that uses the `personA` and `personB` variable names directly.
4. Your `WHERE` clause would allow the same pair of `Person` nodes to be processed twice (in reverse order). You can ensure that the same pair is processed only once by using, for instance, `ID(personA) < ID(personB)` instead of `personA <> personB`.
5. `CREATE UNIQUE` is deprecated, and `MERGE` should be used instead.
6. `MERGE` does not require you to specify the directionality of a relationship -- it can automatically assign one for you. This is appropriate if you want to consider the relationship as undirected (which is true in your case).

Here is a query that takes care of all the above items:

```
MATCH (personA:Person), (personB:Person)
WHERE ID(personA) < ID(personB) AND personA.born = personB.born
MERGE (personA)-[:HAS_SAME_AGE {sameAge: "Has same age"}]-(personB)
```

Note: You may want to give `sameAge` a boolean value (`true` or `false`). Or, better yet, just eliminate `sameAge` entirely, since the `HAS_SAME_AGE` relationship would only exist if the 2 related nodes have the same age anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This query will create empty nodes and create relationships between the empty node and given node.

The issue here is '**personA**' is not in the scope of 'CREATE UNIQUE'.

You need to pass it along with 'personB' in **second 'with' clause.**

**CREATE UNIQUE** is not supported in new versions of Cypher use **MERGE** instead.

```
MATCH (a:Person)
with a AS personA
MATCH (b:Person)
with personA, b AS personB
WHERE personA.born = personB.born AND personA <> personB
CREATE UNIQUE (personA)-[:HAS_SAME_AGE {sameAge: "Has same age"}]->(personB)
```